# swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens has a path argument, I know I have to put the token's contract address first

Tags: .net, smartcontracts, uniswap, nethereum, pancakeswap

I want to swap a token to BNB

```
function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
  uint amountIn,
  uint amountOutMin,
  address[] calldata path,
  address to,
  uint deadline
) external;
```

I do not know what to put on calldata `path`, I've tried this

```
path
{
  tokenContractAddres,
  wBNBAdress
}
```

And when I do a manual swap on pancakeSwap and check the input data , it basically does this, I've search around , it looks like I have to approve it first, when I look at the transaction hash it shows that approve takes an address (the pancake router) and a `uint256`

So my questions are:

- In the approve function what goes in the uint256 argument?
- After the approve function, how do I get the calldata path for the `swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens` function?

Answer (score 4):

The `swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens` requires the last item of the `path` to be `ETH` always!

In your case, you should use the function `swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens` and the `path` parameter having the exact order of conversions that will be execute to get to your final token. In that case you need to guarantee that those pairs are available in Uniswap in order to define the path.

**Example 1:** You have the token `A` and you want to swap it for token `B`, but Uniswap **doesn't have** a liquidity pool with the pair `A-B`, but it has `A-ETH` and `B-ETH`. In that case you'll have the `path` parameter with the following addresses `[A, ETH, B]`.

**Example 2:** You have the token `A` and you want to swap it for token `B` and Uniswap has a liquidity pool with the pair `A-B`. You simply pass the `path` argument with `[A, B]`.

Answer (score 1):

1. The `approve() function` about ERC20 token allow you to set the address of spendere (typeof: address) and amount that this address can spend (typeof:uint256). Having said that, in the approve function you must to insert:

   - address of your smart contract, because he is the spender of your ERC20 tokens;
   - value: the amount of ERC20 tokens that the address (specified above) can spend.
2. For path to swap the tokens with BNB, you can use this:

   ```
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = address(ERC20_TOKEN_ADDRESS);
    path[1] = UniswapV2Router02.WETH();
   ```

`UniswapV2Router02.WETH()`: this function permit you to have directly the address of native coin (in this case BNB).